# unclassifiable statement at (1) Fortran Error

Tags: fortran

at line 64 confirmed as the errors began

I was asked to modify a legacy code. I have found these  errors when compiling [error compiling picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1k4Y.jpg) . Does anybody know how to solve these errors? I use gfortran as my compiler.

The source code:

```
   * Spectral analysis of measured data *

      PARAMETER (ND=86400,NSP=43200,NND=86400)
      COMMON /WDATA/ WD(NND),WD2(NND)
      COMMON /SPEC/ WSP(NSP)
      COMMON /TSDATA/ TS(ND*2),CTTS(ND*2)
      COMMON /SPDATA/ P(NSP),DF

      REAL MEAN

      DATA DT/1.0/
      DATA COTL/14400.0/
      DATA COTS/600.0/
      PI=3.141593

      OPEN(32,FILE="Pw.txt",STATUS="OLD")

      OPEN(12,FILE="output1",STATUS="UNKNOWN")

      OPEN(13,FILE="output2",STATUS="UNKNOWN")

      DO J=1,NND
          READ(32,*)WD(J)
      END DO

       TOTAL=0.0
       MEAN=0.0
       DO J=1,NND
        TOTAL=TOTAL+WD(J)
       END DO

        MEAN=TOTAL/FLOAT(NND)

        DO J=1,NND
         WD(J)=WD(J)-MEAN
        END DO

    Numerical filtering and Spectral analysis

      M=ND/2
      KF=1
      TD=DT*FLOAT(ND)
      DF=1./TD

      DO J=1,ND          
        TS(J)=WD(J)
        TS(J+ND)=0.
      END DO  

      COFL=1./COTL
      COFH=1./COTS
      NCUTL=IFIX((COFL+DF/2.)/DF)+1
      NCUTH=IFIX((COFH-DF/2.)/DF)+1
      =========================  
      CALL CUTOFF(M,NCUTL,NCUTH)
      =========================
      DO J=1,ND
        WD2(J)=CTTS(J)
      END DO
     =================================
      SUBROUTINE CUTOFF(M,NCUTL,NCUTH)
     =================================
      PARAMETER(ND=86400,NSP=43200)
      COMMON /TSDATA/ TS(ND*2),CTTS(ND*2)
      COMMON /FFTDATA/ W1(ND*2)
      MM=M+M
      M4=MM+MM

      DO J=1,MM
        W1(2*J-1)=TS(J)
    W1(2*J)=TS(J+MM)
      END DO
      ===============
      CALL FOUR1(MM,1)
      ===============
      DO J=1,M
        IF(J.EQ.1.AND.NCUTL.GT.0)THEN
      W1(1)=0.
      W1(2)=0.
        ELSE IF(J.LT.NCUTL)THEN
      W1(2*J-1)=0.
      W1(2*J)=0.
      W1(M4-2*J+3)=0.
      W1(M4-2*J+4)=0.
    END IF  
        IF(J.GT.NCUTH)THEN
      W1(2*J-1)=0.
      W1(2*J)=0.
      W1(M4-2*J+3)=0.
      W1(M4-2*J+4)=0.
    END IF
    IF(NCUTH.GT.M) THEN
      W1(MM+1)=0.
      W1(MM+2)=0.
    END IF
      END DO

     -----------------
      CALL FOUR1(MM,-1)
     -----------------

      DO I=1,MM
        CTTS(I)=W1(2*I-1)/FLOAT(MM)
        CTTS(I+MM)=W1(2*I)/FLOAT(MM)
      END DO

      RETURN
      END

     ==========================
      SUBROUTINE FOUR1(NN,ISIGN)
     ==========================
      PARAMETER(ND=86400)
      REAL*8 WR,WI,WPR,WPI,WTEMP,THETA
      COMMON /FFTDATA/ DATA(ND*2)C
      N=2*NN
      J=1
      DO 11 I=1,N,2
        IF(J.GT.I) THEN
      TEMPR=DATA(J)
      TEMPI=DATA(J+1)
      DATA(J)=DATA(I)
      DATA(J+1)=DATA(I+1)
      DATA(I)=TEMPR
      DATA(I+1)=TEMPI
    ENDIF
    M=N/2
    1   IF ((M.GE.2).AND.(J.GT.M)) THEN
          J=J-M
      M=M/2
    GO TO 1
    ENDIF
    J=J+M

        11 CONTINUE
      MMAX=2
    2 IF (N.GT.MMAX) THEN
        ISTEP=2*MMAX
    THETA=6.28318530717959D0/(ISIGN*MMAX)
    WPR=-2.D0*DSIN(0.5D0*THETA)**2
    WPI=DSIN(THETA)
    WR=1.D0
    WI=0.D0
    DO 13 M=1,MMAX,2
      DO 12 I=M,N,ISTEP
      J=I+MMAX
      TEMPR=SNGL(WR)*DATA(J)-SNGL(WI)*DATA(J+1)
      TEMPI=SNGL(WR)*DATA(J+1)+SNGL(WI)*DATA(J)
      DATA(J)=DATA(I)-TEMPR
      DATA(J+1)=DATA(I+1)-TEMPI
      DATA(I)=DATA(I)+TEMPR
      DATA(I+1)=DATA(I+1)+TEMPI
    12     CONTINUE
        WTEMP=WR
       WR=WR*WPR-WI*WPI+WR
      WI=WI*WPR+WTEMP*WPI+WI
    13   CONTINUE
        MMAX=ISTEP
      GO TO 2
      ENDIF
      RETURN
      END
```

Comment: Put the error as a text inside the question. This is quite essential.

Comment: Do all your statements start after column 6? It is not clear from the code you posted. All comments must start in column 1.

Comment: Please, what should your edit mean? Where is line 64? Did you check what I asked?

Comment: sorry, which one the column 6 did you mean ?
line 64 is signed 2 line after "SUBROUTINE CUTOFF", from this line the errors is began,

Comment: Read slide number 3 in http://www.meteor.iastate.edu/classes/mt227/lectures/Fortran77_2009.pdf and read it very carefully. If you do not understand it, find *fixed source form* in any Fortran textbook. This knowledge is **absolutely essential!**.

Comment: The last sentence in the linked slide is wrong, disregard it.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't closed the main program with an `end` statement before the `subroutine cutoff` statement

```
      DO J=1,ND
          WD2(J)=CTTS(J)
      END DO
      =================================
      SUBROUTINE CUTOFF(M,NCUTL,NCUTH)
      =================================
```

This should read something like

```
      DO J=1,ND
         WD2(J)=CTTS(J)
      END DO
      END
      SUBROUTINE CUTOFF(M,NCUTL,NCUTH)
```

however that doesn't really make sense. I'm sure there are more missing lines. There are also many illegal statements in the code presented mostly due to bad formatting as Vladimir F has noted.

Answer (score 2):

Muhajjir,

If gfortran is anything like fortran used to be, this code will generate a
plethora of errors. One thing is for sure, there does HAVE to be and END statment at the end of the main. Otherwise, the compiler gets VERY confused. In
addition, some of your statments appear to have code to the left of column 7. 
Remember, fortran dates from the days of IBM punch cards, which were HIGHLY
column oriented. A capital 'c' was typically used, in column 1, to indicate a
comment. Column 6 was reserved for continuation character, which eventually 
became any character you wanted, as long as column 6 was not empty. Numbers used as labels HAD to start in column 1 and could not go past column 5 into 6, or beyond. This code looks like many of these basic rules have been violated. Check everything, straighten it all out, and everythng should be fine. If not, we can go from there.

```
                                 Blake Mitchell
                                 Retired free lance programmer
```

P.S. To whom it may concern,
I have read through the how to answer link and this answer appears to fit the
requirements perfectly. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for posting an answer. Please look through the [how to answer guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). As written, your answer does not fit on SO.

Comment: Your answer should be in Q/A format, not an email style. Also, citations  improve answers. Last, your answer isn't formatted well. I would suggest browsing SO more to see get a feel for SO.